# How to correctly use font awesome icons in a nativescript application

Tags: nativescript, font-awesome

I have this defined in  my app.scss

```
.fas {
font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free', 'fa-solid-900';
font-weight: 900;
}
```

and am trying to use an icon like this

```
<Button class="btn fas" text="&#xf095;"></Button>
```

in my app. which renders as

[image]

from my reading this *should* work, but I am obviously missing some config item.
Any ideas what I could be missing?

Comment: I don't notice anything obviously wrong.  You do have the Font Awesome 5 fonts in the app/fonts folder, yes?

Comment: That I do. It came with the rest of the generated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had more luck using the following format of the code when using icon fonts.

```js
const icon = String.fromCharCode(0xf095);
```

```html
<Button class="btn fas" [text]="icon"></Button>
```